Static variables get in a way of unit testing with WebApplicationFactory in xUinit
I have a WebApplicationFactory which makes a call to MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap, which is fine when my first test run, but the second test crashes with error because this method was already called with similar args, because it's state is preserved in static field. I can't alter the code that causes the error.
Clearly, when I run all unit tests, they share the same environment with the same static variables. Can I somehow make sure that each test class run in different environment? The same effect as if I ran each test manually and separately.

I would argue that this is duplicate, if the linked answer does not help/clears the case please ping me, I will reopen this one.

It seems to be duplicate. However, no helpful response for me there, because it doesn't seem to have an answer at all.

That is not much you can do here AKAIK. If you can send me a [mre] I will try to check it out later but in short - you can try running webapp in separate process or use custom registrations.
